# Will a CDMA carrier's LTE work on a GSM-only phone?

Tags: 4g, gsm, carriers, cdma

More specifically, I'd like to know if a Sprint-based carrier (Tello) will work on a Xiaomi Redmi Note 8 (M1908C3JG).

Answer (score 0):

**No**

[Will my phone work](https://willmyphonework.net/) says Redmi Note **7** does not work on Tello.

Readme [Note 7](https://m.gsmarena.com/xiaomi_redmi_note_7-9513.php) has more operating frequencies than Readme [Note 8](https://m.gsmarena.com/xiaomi_redmi_note_8-9814.php) (see Network section- 
Note 8 frequencies are a sub set of Note 7 ) but Readme Note 7 doesn't work with Tello.

If you switch carriers, you have a 25 % coverage as indicated [here](https://www.frequencycheck.com/country-compatibility/vEzwy/united-states/devices?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q%5Bfull_name_cont%5D=Redmi+note+8&q%5Bdevice_brand_id_eq%5D=171&commit=Search), but that would need you to do homework to find out which carrier and if that frequency (s) are used where you operate